# Aspnet Core Identity management always returning me to the login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In My application my account manage page is not working I am trying to go to the following.

https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Manage

Which is where the pages for identy manage should be according to my scaffolding, i have changed the code to ensure it points to my ApplicaitonUser Class but for some reason when i access that page its throwing me back to the login even though I have logged in with the login page.

[image]

I have configured my start-up class as such

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    config.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultAuthenticatorProvider;
    config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MSFSAddonDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>,
AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
services.AddSession(opts =>
{
    opts.Cookie.IsEssential = false; // make the session cookie Essential
});
```

Ensuring that the cookie warning is disable as I Believe it can cause issues if not setup yet. I have also enabled MFA using the following code.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
{
    config.Cookie.Name = "Identity.Cookie";
    config.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
options.AddPolicy("TwoFactorEnabled",
 x => x.RequireClaim("amr", "mfa")));
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

The cookie is being created in edge in the debug tabs so I no its being created any idea why my code is refusing to go to the management page I am trying to follow the guide here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0

For complete here is my configure settings

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
        
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I had AddDefaultUI  which over ride the path so the page was never being found. Leaving this herre for anyone else this is asp.net core 5.